# Problema en el maquetado de login

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un maquetado de login con html,css y bootstrap. La idea es que en una mitad aparezcan los campos para poner tus datos y en la otra mitad una imagen. Mi imagen que saque de Google me queda muy borrosa. Use el object-fit: cover en css y se lo aplica a la etiqueta de la imagen pero igualmente me queda muy fea. Alguna solución se le ocurre a alguien?

Comment: Me queda la duda, si es la mitad de arriba o la de abajo? izquierda o derecha? quizás en diagonal?

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Es muy probable que la imagen quede borrosa porque está siendo redimensionada más allá de lo razonable. Hay otras razones, así que es imposible responder sin ver la imagen y el código con el que se monta.